# Deploying Next Js application to Firebase Hosting

Tags: reactjs, firebase, deployment, next.js, firebase-hosting

I selected '.next' folder as the public folder and gave firebase deploy command. The deployment was completed successfully however my website is not being shown. What could be the reason? How should I deploy Next Js application to Firebase Hosting?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know Firebase hosting is for static sites. If you use SSR its not possible (or very hard) to deploy Nextjs app.

If you only use SSG from next and get build with command "next export" that is should be easy to deploy this build folder which should be called 'out'.

more info here https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export